# Uncaught Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'messages.user._id'

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm pretty new to RN, so I started off with a [source code](https://github.com/avegrv/react-native-firebase-chat). When I switched the provided database to mine, I am getting the error Uncaught Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'messages.user._id'. Please help!